# converting seconds to hours,minutes, and seconds?

Tags: java

so Im trying to make a program that can convert s from input into h, m and s. my code so far looks like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class q2_5{
  public static void main(String args[]){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int s=0;//seconds
    int m=0;//minutes
    int h=0;//hour
    System.out.println("how many seconds?");
    s=input.nextInt();
    if(s >= 60){
      m=s/60;
    } if(m>=60){
      h=m/60;
    }
    System.out.println(s + "s = " + h + " h " + m + " m " + s + "s ");
  }
}
```

ok so I had to initialize s,m,h to 0 cuz if not I was getting problems in the if statement, so I just put it to 0, since I can change it later :) ok. so the problem with this program right now is that if I type in 3603 I get this output: 3603s = 1 h 60 m 3603s, if I type in 3600 I get this: 
3600s = 1 h 60 m 3600s, but the output should have been 3603s = 1h 0m 3s and 3600s = 1h 0m 0s respectively. any tips/advice/solutions on how to solve this problem? :D thanks in advance!

Comment: Your posted code was all left-justified making it unreadable. I have tried to fix this. In the future, please fix this yourself. If we can't read your code, we can't understand it nor can we help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never changed the value of `s`. A quick work around would be `s = s - (h*3600 + m*60)`

EDIT: `t = s - (h*3600 + m*60)`

Comment: awesome man, I tried this but the problem is now that I get it right but like it says 0s = 1h 0m 0s if I type in 3600? do I need to make an additional variable or something?

Comment: Then change `s` to something else like `t`.

Comment: hehe thanks man! btw its t = s + (h*3600 + m*60) not t = s - (h*3600 + m*60) :D

Answer (score 6):

Obviously you are doing some homework/practice to learn Java. But FYI, in real work you needn't do those calculations and manipulations. There’s a class for that.

## java.time.Duration

For a span of time, use the [`Duration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class. No need for you to do the math.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofSeconds( s );
```

The standard [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format for a string representing a span of time unattached to the timeline is close to your desired output: `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS` where the P marks the beginning and the T separates any years-months-days from any hours-minutes-seconds. So an hour and a half is `PT1H30M`.

The java.time classes use the ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing or generating strings.

```
String output = d.toString() ;
```

In Java 9 and later, you can call the `to…Part` methods to retrieve the individual parts of hours, minutes, and seconds.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

Comment: Note that the `Duration` class requires Android API level 26 or higher: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/Duration If you still need it maybe this is a possible workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61218004/1306012

Comment: @BrunoBieri I added the *About java.time* section to address your issue of Android version support.

Answer (score 5):

My solution is:

```
 String secToTime(int sec) {
    int second = sec % 60;
    int minute = sec / 60;
    if (minute >= 60) {
        int hour = minute / 60;
        minute %= 60;
        return hour + ":" + (minute < 10 ? "0" + minute : minute) + ":" + (second < 10 ? "0" + second : second);
    }
    return minute + ":" + (second < 10 ? "0" + second : second);
}
```

Comment: in the block `if(minute >= 60)`, it should be `hour = minute/60`.

Comment: Thanks @PantelisSopasakis

Answer (score 4):

Java 8 brings a great API for date and time manipulation.

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Converter {

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");

    public String convert(int seconds) {
        LocalTime time = LocalTime.MIN.plusSeconds(seconds).toLocalTime();

        return formatter.format(time);
    }
}
```

Basically, this code adds the number of number of seconds to the minimum datetime supported, which, naturally, has HH:mm:ss equals to 00:00:00.

As your are interested in the time only, you extract it by calling **toLocalTime()** and format it as wanted.

Comment: Why not shorten that by going straight to `LocalTime` without `LocalDateTime`? `LocalTime.MIN.plusHours( h ).plusMinutes( m ).plusSeconds( s )`

Comment: No need for the `DateTimeFormatter` in this case. The desired output is in standard ISO 8601 format. The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing and generating strings. `myLocalTime.toString()` So your entire code could be reduced to simply: `LocalTime.MIN.plusHours( h ).plusMinutes( m ).plusSeconds( s ).toString()` No real need for a subroutine.

Comment: @BasilBourque, you're right. I've just updated the code. Regarding the formatter, although the question asks for a specific format, I let it for completeness in case someone else is interested in a different format.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it all in a single line:

```
System.out.println((s/3600) + ' hours ' + ((s/60)%60) + ' minutes ' + (s%60) + ' seconds');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try subtracting from the first term every time you set a lower term.

```
class Test{
  public static void main(String args[]){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int s=0;//seconds
    int m=0;//minutes
    int h=0;//hour
    System.out.println("how many seconds?");
    s=input.nextInt();
    if(s >= 60){
      m=s/60;
      s = s- m*60;
    } if(m>=60){
      h=m/60;
      m = m - h*60;
    }
    System.out.println(s + "s = " + h + " h " + m + " m " + s + "s ");
  }
}
```

Just by the way, too, remember to close your `input` scanner! Like so : `input.close()` near the end of the program.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Time_converter {


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        int seconds;
        int minutes ;
        int hours;
        System.out.print("Enter the number of seconds : ");
        seconds = input.nextInt();
        hours = seconds / 3600;
        minutes = (seconds%3600)/60;
        int seconds_output = (seconds% 3600)%60;


        System.out.println("The time entered in hours,minutes and seconds is:");
        System.out.println(hours  + " hours :" + minutes + " minutes:" + seconds_output +" seconds"); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prg2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int seconds = 0;
        int hours = 0;
        int minutes = 0;
        int secondsDisp = 0;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of seconds: ");
        seconds = in.nextInt();
        hours = seconds/3600;
        minutes = (seconds - (hours*3600))/60;
        secondsDisp = ((seconds - (hours*3600)) - (minutes * 60));
        System.out.println(seconds + " seconds equals " + hours + " hours, " + minutes + " minutes and " + secondsDisp + " seconds");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class time{
    public static void main (String args[]){
        int duration=1500;
         String testDuration = "";

        if(duration < 60){
            testDuration = duration + " minutes";
        }
        else{

            if((duration / 60)<24)
            {
                if((duration%60)==0){
                    testDuration = (duration / 60) + " hours";
                }
                else{
            testDuration = (duration / 60) + " hours," + (duration%60) + " minutes";
                }
            }
            else{

                if((duration%60)==0){
                    if(((duration/60)%24)==0){
                        testDuration = ((duration / 24)/60) + " days,";

                    }
                    else{
                    testDuration = ((duration / 24)/60) + " days," + (duration/60)%24 +"hours";
                    }
                }
                    else{
                testDuration = ((duration / 24)/60) + " days," + (duration/60)%24 +"hours"+ (duration%60) + " minutes";
                    }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(testDuration);
    }
}
```

Comment: This assumes the input is minutes and you will convert it to days:hours:minutes which is not the question. You could easily modify it to address the exact question though.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution would be:

```
T = in.nextInt();

int s = T%60;

int minute = T/60;

int m = minute%60;

int h = minute/60;

return h+"h"+m+"m"+s+"s";
```

Answer (score -1):

use this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class q2_5{
public static void main(String args[]){

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int s=0;//seconds
int m=0;//minutes
int h=0;//hour
int s_input=0;
System.out.println("how many seconds?");
s_input=input.nextInt();
s=s_input%60;
if(s >= 60){

m=s_input/60;
}if(m>=60){

h=m/60;
m=m%60;
}
System.out.println(s + "s = " + h + " h " + m + " m " + s + "s ");
 }
}
```