# convert local Date time to UTC format

Tags: android, kotlin

i want to convert this 01/20/2021 20:10:14 to this format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'  in android.
currently i am using function but when i convert to local format i don't get original time

```
fun convertDate (date : String) : String {
        var convertedDate = ""
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        val timeformat = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")
        val time = timeformat.format(calendar.time)
        val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
        val odate = formatter.parse(date+" "+time)
        val utcformat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
        convertedDate = utcformat.format(odate)
        return convertedDate
    }
```

Comment: Try setting the TimeZone on the calendar instance

Answer (score 1):

You should use the modern `java.time` API for dates, times, etc.

Firstly we need to format the input string. As mentioned in the comment in the question, the zone information is required to correctly format the input date string.

This gives us a [`TemporalAccessor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAccessor.html) object. Now, we need to convert this object to an object of the [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class. An `Instant` object is always treated to be at UTC.

```kotlin
fun convertDate (date : String) : String {
    val formatter = DateTimeFormatter
        .ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
        .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())

    val instant = Instant.from(formatter.format(date))
    return instant.toString()
}
```

Comment: that's correct, but the formatter pattern should be "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'" according to the question ;)

Comment: The pattern here is that of the input string. The 'Z' in output string symbolizes UTC time. That is being done through the `Instant` object

Comment: @KyzerSoze i know that class but this class is supported from API level 26 and my minsdk is 21 so i can not use this class

Comment: If possible, you can use [desugaring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61218004/12313157)